# Deletion of grouping in jquery.datatable

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, datatables

I am using first time datatable in one of project.
I am also using row grouping for grouping feature.

Issue is that in few cases I am deleting and recreating tables for grouping or ungrouping etc.

```
function DestroyTable(table)
        {
            if(table != null) 
            {
                table.fnDestroy();  //destroy
            }
            var ogroups = table.dataTableExt.aoGroups;
            for(var group in ogroups) {
                    ogroups[group].nGroup.remove();
                }
            }
        }
```

Issues I am facing is remove function is not working in IE 8,9,10.
I am seeing this is working fine, perfectly in google chrome and firefox.

Let me know what I can do here?

Regards,
Chakresh

Comment: Error in IE console? What is not working in IE? Describe it

Comment: for this functiona call ogroups[group].nGroup.remove(); I am getting error Object doesn't support property or method 'remove'